# Microsoft SQL Server, Apache and PHP error

Tags: php, angularjs, sql-server, apache

I'm currently doing a website using AngularJS, CakePHP for web services and Microsoft Sql Server 2008 for DB. It was working OK until yesterday that my coworker and I started to test the site at the same time and the server kept freezing. We restarted the SQL server several times, it did not work. We tried restarting the Apache server and it kept doing the same thing.
We are using Xampp version 1.8.3.
We don't know what can be causing this misbehavior.
Any help will be very appreciated

This is what the php error logs file shows:

> PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\reinier\lib\Cake\Model\Datasource\CakeSession.php on line 694

Answer (score 0):

Easy, just add the CommandTimeout=600 to your connection string. This will change the timeout from 30 seconds to 600 seconds.

In PHP you want to specify the QueryTimeout in the sqlsrv_query array.

Comment: This is what I set in the php.ini file mssql.timeout = 600
 and mssql.connect_timeout = 600, and in the SQL Management Studio I set the server remote timeout to 0 (no timeout), and the problem persists.

Comment: [ConnectionTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout.aspx) and [CommandTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx) are not the same, try the CommandTimeout

Comment: Where do I specify this? In SQLServer or in CakePHP?

Comment: Check out this link: [sqlsrv_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php) it is called QueryTimeout in PHP. Yes in PHP where you specify the query.